# Command not found error for starting backgroundrb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, backgroundrb

Getting error while starting the [backgroundrb](https://github.com/gnufied/backgroundrb) job.

command:

```
sanjaya:-/Documents/proj_location $ sudo ./script/backgroundrb start
```

error:

```
sudo: ./script/backgroundrb: command not found
```

Searched through Internet but not getting any feasible solution to this.